# how can i take array values dynamically in php

Tags: php

Thanks in advance everybody, Actually I have an array with "BUSINESS_NAME" there are FOOD AND GROCERY and NONFOOD so I want to separate for `[series_name] => "FOOD AND GROCERY" with array values and [series_name] => "NONFOOD" with different values.`
So my array is

```
<?php

$arrFirst = Array
(
    "0" => Array
        (
            "BUSINESS_NAME" => "FOOD AND GROCERY",
            "Division_name" => "BAKERY AND CONCEPTS",
            "value" => 0.0009477694110518376
        ),

    "1" => Array
        (
            "BUSINESS_NAME" => "FOOD AND GROCERY",
            "Division_name" => "DAIRY AND FROZEN",
            "value" => 0.005450625689261974
        ),

    "2" => Array
        (
            "BUSINESS_NAME" => "FOOD AND GROCERY",
            "Division_name" => "FISH AND MEAT",
            "value" => 0.000021331155586759062
        ),

  "3" => Array
        (
            "BUSINESS_NAME" => "FOOD AND GROCERY",
            "Division_name" => "FOODS",
           "value" => 7.763433792429072 
        ),

    "4" => Array
        (
            "BUSINESS_NAME" => "FOOD AND GROCERY",
            "Division_name" => "FMCGFOODS",
            "value" => 28.280507791758872
        ),

    "5" => Array
        (
            "BUSINESS_NAME" => "FOOD AND GROCERY",
            "Division_name" => "FRUIT AND VEG",
            "value" => 0.00004250371522120021
        ),

    "6" => Array
        (
            "BUSINESS_NAME" => "FOOD AND GROCERY",
            "Division_name" => "LIQUOR AND TOBACCO",
            "value" => 0.0001807993856424188
        ),

    "7" => Array
        (
            "BUSINESS_NAME" => "FOOD AND GROCERY",
            "Division_name" => "STAPLES",
            "value" => 63.63833077404931
        ),

    "8" => Array
        (
            "BUSINESS_NAME" => "NONFOOD",
            "Division_name" => "APPARELS",
            "value" => 0.009254311711678597
        ),

    "9" => Array
        (
            "BUSINESS_NAME" => "NONFOOD",
            "Division_name" => "ELECTRONICS",
            "value" => 0.0009884492728213818
        ),

    "10" => Array
        (
            "BUSINESS_NAME" => "NONFOOD",
            "Division_name" => "GENERALMERCHANDISING",
            "value" => 0.051390163621477414
        ),

    "11" => Array
        (
            "BUSINESS_NAME" => "NONFOOD",
            "Division_name" => "MAX",
            "value" => 0.23221365584864856
        ),

    "12" => Array
        (
            "BUSINESS_NAME" => "NONFOOD",
            "Division_name" => "TEXTILES",
            "value" => 0.01723803195136225
        )

);
```

I need a dynamic array like this as below

```
Array
(
    [BUSINESS_NAME] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (

                            [series_name] => FOOD AND GROCERY
                                (
                                    [0] => 0.00094776941105184
                                    [1] => 0.005450625689262
                                    [2] => 2.1331155586759E-5
                                    [3] => 7.7634337924291
                                    [4] => 28.280507791759
                                    [5] => 4.25037152212E-5
                                    [6] => 0.00018079938564242
                                    [7] => 63.638330774049
                                )



                )

            [1] => Array
                (

                            [series_name] => NONFOOD
                                (
                                    [0] => 0.0092543117116786
                                    [1] => 0.00098844927282138
                                    [2] => 0.051390163621477
                                    [3] => 0.23221365584865
                                    [4] => 0.017238031951362
                                )



                )

        )

)
```

I got a reference from google using

```
foreach ($arrFirst as $value) {
    $businesArr[$value['BUSINESS_NAME']]['series_name'][] = $value['value'];   
}

foreach ($businesArr as $key => $value) {
    $finalArr['BUSINESS_NAME'][][$key] = $value;   
}
```

but the array looks different

Comment: Result array is unclear and not valid.  Is `NONFOOD` an element of `series_name` along with the values or is it an array that holds the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and see the output and update accordingly.
**UPDATED** and matching with your **output** (Exactly)

```
$tmp = array();
foreach($arrFirst as $arg)
{
    $tmp[$arg['BUSINESS_NAME']][] = $arg['value'];
}

$output = array();
foreach($tmp as $name => $values)
{
    $output['BUSINESS_NAME'][] = array(
        'series_name' => $name,
        'value' => $values
    );
}
```

[image]

Comment: what you did is correct but i need these array data inside [BUSINESS_NAME] => Array
        (

Comment: you can update this and make as you want. write $output['BUSINESS_NAME'][] instead of just $output[] inside second loop and see the result. Update accordingly.

Comment: No yaar, I will get only NONFOOD array like this Array
(
    [BUSINESS_NAME] => Array
        (
            [series_name] => NONFOOD
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0.0092543117116786
                    [1] => 0.00098844927282138
                    [2] => 0.051390163621477
                    [3] => 0.23221365584865
                    [4] => 0.017238031951362
                )

        )

)

Comment: Oh Thank you very much yaar.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, except instead of numeric keys under `BUSINESS_NAME` you will have the actual `BUSINESS_NAME` value from the original array:

```
foreach($arrFirst as $array) {
    $result["BUSINESS_NAME"][$array["BUSINESS_NAME"]]
           ["series_name"][$array["BUSINESS_NAME"]][] = $array["value"];
}
```

Comment: Liked it, nice but more array hierarchy on output.

Answer (score -1):

Your first script only defines one array, so I'm not sure why you are referring to $businessArr in that second script.

Your destination array looks a little weird too. I'm not sure your pasted output there is a valid var_dump output, but I'll try.

```
$destArray = array(
    "BUSINESS_NAME" => array(
        array(
            0 => array("series_name" => "FOOD AND GROCERY"),
            1 => array("series_name" => "NONFOOD")
        )
    )

);

foreach($arrFirst as $record) {
    if ($record["BUSINESS_NAME"] == "FOOD AND GROCERY") {
        $destArray["BUSINESS_NAME"][0][] = $record["value"];
    } elseif ($record["BUSINESS_NAME"] == "NONFOOD") {
        $destArray["BUSINESS_NAME"][1][] = $record["value"];
    }
}
```

Personally, I would not define that second array like that. I also feel that your original post could use some improvement in terms of expressing what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What if i have one more series name as series_name" => "SEAFOOD", He needs to update his code accordingly right?

Comment: see the solution posted by @AbraCadaver, that's also dynamic sir.

Comment: As I said, the OP needs to provide more detail about exactly needs to be accomplished. AbraCadaver's solution is pretty elegant, but the output is a bit whack: